# Multiple RPMs unpacking to the same directories-best practices and rationale

Tags: filesystems, rpm, package-managers

From what I've seen in documentation, when unpacking an RPM, best practices are to unpack it in `/opt/<provider>/<package>`. My question is, is there a compelling reason from either a system administration or technical perspective why it wouldn't be acceptable to unpack multiple RPMs to a further subdirectory?

For example, if I have `/opt/<provider>`, is it safe to have multiple RPMs create `/opt/<provider>/<subdir>` then unpack there such that I would end up with `/opt/<provider>/<subdir>/<packagA>` and `/opt/<provider>/<subdir>/<packageB>` where `<subdir>` is a directory that is mapped in both RPMs? If this isn't safe, why not?

Answer (score 0):

In RPM , you would be mentioning the files and folders which are owned by RPM .

If you are able to handle above scenario well, I dont think it will create a problem

It is not a best practise to unpack new rpm into subdirectory of folder owned by existing RPM

Comment: Could you clarify please? I'm currently able to handle it, yes, but why is it not best practice? Is there a possible problem down the road that I'm missing? A gotcha that I'm not currently aware of? If unpacking a new rpm into  a subdirectory already owned by an existing RPM is not best practice, there must be a reason, right?

Comment: I dont see any problem , as long as if installation of RPM and uninstallation is clean .

Comment: If uninstallation of RPM is not impacting other subdirectories then not an issue .